# How to use Shannon Equation

Tags: space-communications

I just start learning how to calculate Shannon capacity and trying to understand the relationship between power and path loss.

I would like to make sure if I use the equation correctly.

The path loss can be express as

[image]

And the received power would be

[image]

If I would like to calculate the Shannon capacity , it should be like

[image]

(where **B** is bandwidth, **c** is speed of light, **d** is distance between transmitter & receiver, **f** is central frequency)

However, I found a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ziye-Jia/publication/344142999_LEO_Satellite-Assisted_UAV_Joint_Trajectory_and_Data_Collection_for_Internet_of_Remote_Things_in_6G_Aerial_Access_Networks/links/5fb3731c45851518fdacc04a/LEO-Satellite-Assisted-UAV-Joint-Trajectory-and-Data-Collection-for-Internet-of-Remote-Things-in-6G-Aerial-Access-Networks.pdf) that calculate the formula without square of the term in received power.
(I mark the term with red lines)

[image]

Can anyone explain this to me , please ?

**Am I doing the calculation incorrectly or is there an error in the formula in the paper ?**

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly better link, that's not behind a paywall: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ziye-Jia/publication/344142999_LEO_Satellite-Assisted_UAV_Joint_Trajectory_and_Data_Collection_for_Internet_of_Remote_Things_in_6G_Aerial_Access_Networks/links/5fb3731c45851518fdacc04a/LEO-Satellite-Assisted-UAV-Joint-Trajectory-and-Data-Collection-for-Internet-of-Remote-Things-in-6G-Aerial-Access-Networks.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the link in my post with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this link](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ziye-Jia/publication/344142999_LEO_Satellite-Assisted_UAV_Joint_Trajectory_and_Data_Collection_for_Internet_of_Remote_Things_in_6G_Aerial_Access_Networks/links/5fb3731c45851518fdacc04a/LEO-Satellite-Assisted-UAV-Joint-Trajectory-and-Data-Collection-for-Internet-of-Remote-Things-in-6G-Aerial-Access-Networks.pdf), which is not behind a paywall, the author's own (1) says
$$G_{iu} = \delta_0/l^2_{iu}(t).$$

Then their (2) says
$$c_{iu}^t = B_{iu}^t \log_2 \left(1 + \frac{P_{i^t}^{tr} G_{iu}}{\sigma^2}\right) = 
B_{iu}^t \log_2 \left(1 + \frac{P_{i^t}^{tr} \gamma_0}{l_{iu}^2(t)}\right).$$

Then their (3) apparently drops the exponent from the distance.

So -- their paper is in error.  Any far-field communication in this 3D universe of ours is going to have power dropping off as distance squared.

Comment: You may want to send an email to the authors asking them for clarity -- chances are they just forgot the exponent when they went from $l_{iu}^2$ to $l_{us}^t$, because they'd put a $t$ in the superscript.  Even if it is just a clerical error and any computations they did are correct, they should still appreciate knowing there's a misprint.

Comment: Hi @TimWescott , thanks for your check and exposition. Just want to make sure , did I derive the formula correctly ?
$$
R = B \cdot log_2(1+\frac{P_tG_tG_rc^2}{(4\pi df)^2 \cdot Noise})
$$

Comment: Unless there's something very odd hidden in their notation -- yes.

Comment: Thank you , I really appreciated your help.